# where are the IIS server settings stored?

Tags: windows, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have installed [url rewrite tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module). I have set a global rule by right clicking on the server name (not a website name) and created a rule.

Now I want to edit this rule manually but I don't know where these settings are stored? when I create a rule for a website, it is stored in `web.config` but in this case I created rule for whole server and I can not find where it is stored? Is it stored as windows registry key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing a configuration via IIS Manager, the statusbar shows into which file the settings will be stored. At server level it mostly is applicationHost.config which is stored at %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a related question after your answer. please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525867/how-browsers-find-applicationhost-config-file