# How browsers find applicationHost.config file?

Tags: windows, iis, browser, web-config

I was trying to change the name of web.config and read some Q/A about it where the final solution was to reference from `web.config` to an extra config file using `configSource`.

I wonder how browsers know that there is config file in `c:\programfiles\system32\....\ applicationHost.config` when they want to connect to localhost? In other words how IIS notifies the browsers to look for this file rather than the `web.congif` itself? There is no reference to this file in `web.config` in the root of wwwroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the name, it must be web.config by convention.

It's also not the browser that reads these config files but the IIS webserver. IIS 'merges' the settings from applicationHost.config with the web.config(s) of your website and applies them as a whole.

Comment: Thank you . I'm looking for more details that how can I do same merging with two config files without writing something in `web.config` e.g. in a hosted website on hosting companies?

Comment: Can you give more details what settings would be stored into these config files? You rareley touch applicationHost.config and only use web.config(s), for which IIS handles the merging.

Comment: I want to hide some settings from thefts and hackers so I prefer to store them in a secondary config file rather that  the web.config itself. I want to know how IIS make reference to `applicationHost.config` without any visible codes? @pfx

Comment: Using an other config file won't be safer; if a hacker succeeds to access the filesystem of the webserver he will have access to all (config) files. You might store encrypted values.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour if you intend to hide something from others, make that clear by editing your question above. Don't underestimate others please. If you leave `configSource` in your `web.config`, anyone with basic ASP.NET knowledge knows where to locate your moved settings, and it won't give any real protection.

Comment: @LexLi Elimination of configSource is the reason that I asked this question. Im looking for the way that IIS do this without a visible code.